# Need help updating the index for selected row

Tags: javascript, dom

I have been stuck on an issue where I am trying to use Javascript to add and remove  a row from a table.

I got the add part working, the delete somewhat. The delete fails if you delete the first row or a row in the middle (live code can be seen [here](https://teoespero.000webhostapp.com/web-portfolio/to-do-list-v02/)

I uploaded its code on [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/cYyzi81K)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


        var itemNumber = 0
        var currentRow = 0;
        var selectedRow = 0;

        function theIndex(theRow){
            selectedRow = theRow;
        }

        document.getElementById("addItem").addEventListener("click", function(){

            if (document.getElementById('whatToDo').value != ""){
                currentRow++;

                var table = document.getElementById('myList');
                var row = table.insertRow(currentRow);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

                itemNumber++;
                // alert(currentRow);
                // cell1.innerHTML = itemNumber;
                cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById('whatToDo').value;
                cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById('whenToDo').value;
                cell4.innerHTML = document.getElementById('whereToDo').value;
                row.addEventListener('click', theIndex.bind(null, currentRow));

                document.getElementById('whatToDo').value = "";
                document.getElementById('whenToDo').value = "";
                document.getElementById('whereToDo').value = "";
            }
        });


        document.getElementById("removeItem").addEventListener("click", function(){

            // var theRow = document.getElementById('whatToMark').value;
            var theRow = selectedRow;
            alert("index: " +theRow + " elements: " + currentRow);

            if (theRow > 0){

                document.getElementById("myList").deleteRow(theRow);
                document.getElementById('whatToMark').value = "";
                currentRow--;
                itemNumber--;
            }
            selectedRow = 0;
        });

        document.getElementById("markAsDone").addEventListener("click", function(){

            // var theRow = document.getElementById('whatToMark').value;
            var theRow = selectedRow;

            alert("index: " +theRow + " elements: " + currentRow);

            var table = document.getElementById('myList');
            if (theRow != 0){

                table.rows[theRow].style.setProperty("text-decoration", "line-through");
                document.getElementById('whatToMark').value = "";
            }

            selectedRow = 0;
        });

    </script>
```

I am learning Javascript and wanted to do more than the exercise that was being given by adding new features to it.

Comment: Where did you define/assign `selectedRow` variable?

Comment: it looks like he calls it and assigns it here theIndex.bind(null, currentRow));

Comment: I keep getting a null value error when trying to delete something. Error is at Line 131, which is: `document.getElementById('whatToMark').value = "";`. From your HTML, it looks like you never set an element to the id of `whatToMark`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach to mark the current selected row has some issues:

```
row.addEventListener('click', theIndex.bind(null, currentRow));
```

Instead of using a global variable I suggest to use a row attribute (or class). Hence, change that line to:

```
row.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.querySelectorAll('tr[selected]').forEach(function(item) {
        item.removeAttr('selected');
    })
    row.setAttribute('selected', true);
});
```

Add the attribute selected for the current row and remove the same attribute for other rows.

In this way, when you need to get the current selected row you can simply:

```
var rSelected = document.querySelector('tr[selected]');
var theRow = (rSelected == null) ? 0 : rSelected.rowIndex;
```

```js
var itemNumber = 0
var currentRow = 0;
var selectedRow = 0;

function theIndex(theRow) {
    selectedRow = theRow;
}
document.getElementById("addItem").addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (document.getElementById('whatToDo').value != "") {
        currentRow++;
        var table = document.getElementById('myList');
        var row = table.insertRow(currentRow);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

        itemNumber++;
        // alert(currentRow);
        // cell1.innerHTML = itemNumber;
        cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById('whatToDo').value;
        cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById('whenToDo').value;
        cell4.innerHTML = document.getElementById('whereToDo').value;
        //row.addEventListener('click', theIndex.bind(null, currentRow));
        row.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            document.querySelectorAll('tr[selected]').forEach(function(item) {
                item.removeAttr('selected');
            })
            row.setAttribute('selected', true);
        });

        document.getElementById('whatToDo').value = "";
        document.getElementById('whenToDo').value = "";
        document.getElementById('whereToDo').value = "";
    }
});


document.getElementById("removeItem").addEventListener("click", function () {
    // var theRow = document.getElementById('whatToMark').value;
    var rSelected = document.querySelector('tr[selected]');
    var theRow = (rSelected == null) ? 0 : rSelected.rowIndex;
    if (theRow > 0) {
        document.getElementById("myList").deleteRow(theRow);
        //document.getElementById('whatToMark').value = "";
        currentRow--;
        itemNumber--;
    }
    selectedRow = 0;
});

document.getElementById("markAsDone").addEventListener("click", function () {
    // var theRow = document.getElementById('whatToMark').value;
    var theRow = selectedRow;
    alert("index: " + theRow + " elements: " + currentRow);
    var table = document.getElementById('myList');
    if (theRow != 0) {

        table.rows[theRow].style.setProperty("text-decoration", "line-through");
        document.getElementById('whatToMark').value = "";
    }
    selectedRow = 0;
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <h1>To Do List Example</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><label>Item</label></th>
                    <th><label>Date</label></th>
                    <th><label>Location</label></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="whatToDo" value="">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="date" id="whenToDo" value="">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="whereToDo" value="">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button id="addItem" class="btn btn-default btn-primary active">
                            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add This Item
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="markAsDone" class="btn btn-default ">
                            <i class="fas fa-check"></i> Mark As Done
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="removeItem" class="btn btn-default">
                            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Remove Item
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <table class="table table-hover" id="myList">
                <tr>
                    <th><label></label></th>
                    <th><label>Event</label></th>
                    <th><label>Date</label></th>
                    <th><label>Location</label></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I modified the code as how you have mentioned and it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This line is throwing a null value error:

```
document.getElementById('whatToMark').value = "";
```

Neither in your JS, nor in your HTML, do you ever set an element to the ID of `whatToMark`.

Comment: I've commented out this code, since its a hold over from an older branch.